# Reuse Angular component to load different data without using switch statement

Tags: angular, angular5

I am moving my application from jquery to angular 5.

I have a component called `citySelect.Component.html`

In it I have 3 select boxes -  Country, Province and City

On my city select I have

citySelect.Component.html

```
  <select (change)="onCitySelect($event.target.value)">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of cities" value={{c.id}}>
                    {{c.cityName}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

citySelect.Component.ts

```
onCitySelect(cityId: string) {
    if (cityId != "") {
        this.data.getCityPersons(cityId);
    }
}
```

`getCityPersons` is a method in `dataService.ts` that stored  the persons in a array property in the same dataservice  which allows this array to be used by another component personForm.component

dataService.ts

```
public persons: Person[];
public personsChange: Subject<Person[]> = new Subject<Person[] >();



getCityPersons(cityId: string) {
    this.loadCityPersons(cityId)
        .subscribe(success => {
            if (success) {
                this.personsChange.next(this.persons);
            }
        });
}
```

This all works correct. However I need to reuse the `citySelect.Component` for reporting and other forms.

A solution for reuse I can think of is to 
 can pass an @Input  to the citySelect and then based off that have an if statement in the citySelect e.g.

citySelect.Component.ts

```
@Input() formName: string;
...
onCitySelect(cityId: string) {
    if (this.cityId != "") {
        switch(this.formName) { 
           case 'cityPatient': { 
              this.data.getCityPersons(cityId);
              break; 
           } 
           case 'cityReport1': { 
              this.data.fetchCityReport1(cityId);
              break; 
           } 
            case 'cityCityStats': { 
              this.data.fetchCityStats(cityId);
              break; 
           } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Each of the above fetch components fetches different array objects in the data service which  in turn is referenced in different component.

How do I fix the code so that the component is more isolated from knowing about which data it has to fetch for the various pages that reuse the component for differing data selection

With jquery I could have a event on the citySelect in the various pages and just I reuse the component  without having to  use switch statements.

Comment: Why don't you just send the data to your component instead of `formName`? Call the service method from the parent component, not the component itself and send the data via the @Input()

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be not to use an `@Input` but an `@Output`. You can call the output event each time the user selects a person.

```
<app-city-select (personSelected)="getCityPersons($event)"></app-city-select>
<app-city-select (personSelected)="fetchCityReport($event)"></app-city-select>
<app-city-select (personSelected)="fetchCityStats($event)"></app-city-select>
```